# Tor safe when taking future in to account?

Tags: security, onion-routing, circuit, connection, attacks

With quantum computing becoming better by the day I have a few questions.

How viable and likely is it that an adversary to saves all tor traffic in order to decrypt it at a later date?

When approximately will quantum computers be good enough to decrypt all this data?

Should tor users be worried?

Comment: I don't believe that someone, even if it was a trillionary dude, would waste millions of dollars for saving thousands of GBs that it the daily Tor traffic just for see what pedophiles  are seeing in the deep web when quantum computers are ruling the world. My recommendation is: RELAX.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum threat is a real thing, especially in context of Shor's algorithm for a possible attack vector, for example. But there're a lot of quantum-resistant things like LWE and some EC's, so - using a proper cipher set **and** negotiation mechanism we should not worry about that, at least for some long time. Anyway, your concern is a very good point to re-evaluate the basic things like a cipher sets *and* RNG's used on any SSL connection, I was speaking about it for 10+ years myself :)

Answer (score 0):

> How viable and likely is it that an adversary to saves all tor traffic in order to decrypt it at a later date?

NSA isn't building more and more data warehouses without a reason.

But what makes you think that ALL TOR TRAFFIC is relevant for an adversary to decript and analyse? Most of my Tor browsing is just reading Wikipedia articles. Pretty boring, isn't it?